# Is there some kind of law that restrict the use of nuclear power in Middle Eastern countries?

Tags: middle-east, nuclear-energy

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_power_by_country

I noticed that the UAE and Egypt are the only countries that use nuclear power and that are allowed to use it without sanctions. Iran, however, is not allowed and is heavily sanctioned for using nuclear power, but I would like to know which countries are allowed to use it and what requirements they must abide to in order to use nuclear power.

Comment: [Iran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_program_of_Iran) wasn't sanctioned for using civilian nuclear power but for a suspected weapons program. The NPT and IAEA provide a framework for nations to pursue peaceful nuclear technology, but the key word is peaceful. [Egypt](https://www.power-technology.com/projects/el-dabaa-nuclear-power-plant/) is building a nuclear power plant, but nations with lots of oil have little incentive to pursue expensive and complex nuclear technology.

Comment: Note that there are only about half a dozen companies/ states in the world who have the technological ability to build a nuclear power plant. So if for whatever reason none of them wants to build one in a specific country none gets build.